# Command Line Parameter for current date and time in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, command-line-arguments, run-configuration

I have a java application that writes a file.  One of my command line parameters is the name of the file.  I would like to set a run configuration in eclipse to name the file with the date and time, something like this:

> MyFile_20121018113400.txt

Is there a way to do this in the Run Configurations menu?

EDIT: The date format doesn't have to be exactly that.  I just want a unique filename for each time I generate the file.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Stack Overflow, so apologies if I get this wrong or have misunderstood the question, but can you use:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
```

And format it with a simple date formatter, for example:

```
dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

And then change the format to whatever your want?

Again, apologies if this is unhelpful.

Comment: The date has to come in through a parameter because we sometimes manually call the jar with an older date to rerun old data.  I'm looking for a way to do this through the eclipse IDE, not in the java code itself.